# Extracting part of string from a file in ksh environment

Tags: shell-script, ksh, aix

I have a file that has error messages as per below

```
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1505) 
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at token.c(604)
```

I want to extract the code number eg 23 in the first line and 12 in second.

Comment: Is this a file that contains tho output of _multiple_ `rsync` runs? `rsync` usually uses these codes as exit status, so there's an opportunity to catch them directly from the utility when running it too, by investigating `$?`.

Comment: Yes this file will contain output from many rsync runs.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like

```
$ grep -o "(code [0-9]*" file | cut -d" " -f2
23
12
```

?

Comment: Or, with GNU grep: `grep -oP 'code \K\d+'` or `grep -oP '(?<=code )\d+'`

Comment: unfortunately this is a aix environment and does not support -o for grep and no equivalent flag.

Comment: @Nem `sed -n 's/.*(code \([0-9]*\)).*/\1/p' your_file`

Answer (score 0):

Using awk, you can extract the numbers in various ways. The script below expects to see a pattern of:

1. a space
2. `(`
3. the string `code`
4. a space
5. a sequence of digits
6. `)`
7. a space

... which is not fool-proof, so I try to further limit the scope by restricting the matches to being on lines that start with the string `rsync error:`.

The remaining `print` code simply adjusts the string length parameters to account for the leading and trailing text.

```
awk '/^rsync error: .* \(code [[:digit:]]+\) / \
  { 
    match($0, " \\(code [[:digit:]]+\\) "); 
    print substr($0, RSTART + 7, RLENGTH - 9) ; 
  }' input
```